# Verify user received the confirmation email from cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.SignUpAsync to register congnito users using C# backend code.
Some users complaining they don't receive the confirmation code via email even enter the correct email.
Is there a way to verify that the verification email sent successfully from the AWS userpool

Answer (score 0):

Connect your UserPool to Simple Email Service (SES) as the email provider. SES will then tell you about bounces in case their spam filter has rejected the email or rejected your domain. Setup all the DKIM stuff in SES to maximise your reputation.
In the case of user error, it is hard to actively identify unless you add tracking links / images to your emails.